# Restricting characters in text box

Tags: javascript, function, exception, textbox, restriction

I need to modify this function to work properly. It is supposed to restrict everything but the alphabet, spaces, and apostrophes. Currently it is still restricting apostrophes. I'm assuming the pattern ' \ _ ' is referring to ALL special characters. How would I insert an exception in to this function?

```
function NameNotNA (s) {
        var pattern;
        if (s.toUpperCase().indexOf('N/A') != -1){
            //console.warn('failed in n/a');
            return false;
        }
        // Eliminate possibility of digits
        pattern = /\d/;
        if (s.match(pattern) != null) {

            //console.warn('failed in \d');
            return false;
        }

        pattern = /\_/;
        if (s.match(pattern) != null) { 
            //console.warn('failed in \_');
            return false; 
        }

        s = s.replace(/ /g, '');
        if (s.match(/\W/) != null) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: s.replace(/[^\a-z\s']/ig, '');

Answer (score 0):

```
function nameNotNA (s) {
    return s.replace(/[^\w\s']/g, '');
}
```

For regex, I like using [this tool](https://regex101.com/#javascript) to understand exactly what's happening.  Also, it's good to keep your function names lowerCamelCase unless it's a Class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was able to get it working by adding "throw /\s'/;"

That tool looks handy. Ill be sure to use it in the future.